# Pivot Table Macro Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

[image]I currently have an excel spreadsheet which has some headers like

```
Pers.No.  Employee name   Hours   etc etc
12345       bobby          5.5
12346       jones          6
12345       bobby          7.5
```

However in my pivot table I am only interested in The Pers.No. and Hours to be avaliable like so. Unfortunately the program where I get the original data from gives the persons number multiple times, and displays the work they do every day. So there would be multiple entries of employee `12345` but I want to show this once obviously in the pivot table, and sum all of the hours assigned to this `12345`. This of course can be done manually not too horribly however, I need to make a macro so others can use it.

```
Person.No.     Hours
12345          40
```

**My Attempt**

```
Sub Macro()


    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

    ' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("May20").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    ' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
    Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard

    ' Specify row and column fields.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Pers.No.")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField


    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Hours")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"



    ' Preview the new PivotTable report.
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

    ' Prompt the user whether to delete the PivotTable.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If MsgBox("Delete the PivotTable?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.Delete
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

However I am not sure if I am doing this the right way as I get an error of method `'pivottablewizard' of object '_worksheet' failed` on the line

```
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard
```

Ideally I want it to create a new sheet 1 with the pivot table in it

------------EDIT----------------------------

[image]

Given this with a bunch of more entries I would like to create
A pivot table that looks like

```
Employee ID   Hours

12345          90  
123423         100
```

Now the excel file has multiple entries for employees with the same ID so it needs to sum all those hours in the pivot table

Comment: Least we hope is a prompt feedback on answer or observation provided by us. Learning never ends and we hope your feedback will provide us to refine our analysis. It is not for points on answer but only to validate our analysis. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot about this my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the following line to correctly point to data source.

```
 Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard
```

To

```
 Set objTable = Sheets("May20").PivotTableWizard
```

Hope it will enable you to proceed further.Pivot Table Wizard should create Pivot Table in new sheet.

**EDIT**

> I get an error object required on line "Set objField =
>   objTable.PivotFields("Hours")"

This error could be caused if the field names in your code and the physical sheet are not matching.

Following code slightly modified based on your code is working fine. I have also appended snapshots of sample data, pivot table and report. One care is needed always come out of Debug Mode from VBE by pressing   ALT+Q before again running the program and also delete worksheet containing Pivot Table as a precautionary measure if you run into error while running the program.

```
Sub Macro()


    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

    ' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("May20").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    ' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
    Set objTable = Sheets("May20").PivotTableWizard

    ' Specify row and column fields.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Pers.No.")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField


    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Hours")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    'objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"



    ' Preview the new PivotTable report.
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

    ' Prompt the user whether to delete the PivotTable.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If MsgBox("Delete the PivotTable?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.Delete
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

[image: Sample data]
[image: Pivot Table]
[image: Report]

**EDIT**

I feel that if you want filtered for a particular person, it should be in page field. Following Macro recorded by me gives output for a selected person as shown in the snapshot.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:E7").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$7"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table1", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet6!R3C1", _
        TableName:="PivotTable7", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet6!$A$3:$C$20")
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Pers.No.")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.AddDataField ActiveChart.PivotLayout. _
        PivotTable.PivotFields("Hours"), "Sum of Hours", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Pers.No.").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Pers.No.").CurrentPage = _
        "12345"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Employee name   H")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("CD1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("CD2")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Pers.No.").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(-1).PivotFields("Pers.No.").CurrentPage = "12345"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").ShowPages PageField:="Pers.No."
End Sub
```

[image: snapshot1]
[image: snapshot2]
[image: snapshot3]

Comment: I get an error object required on line "Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Hours")"

Comment: What if I want to add the total hours associated with an id? From my file I have multiple same ids say 12345 which have 5 hours multiple ties. I want to sum hours based on the same ID not everyones hours in total. Thanks for your help by the wa

Comment: Also I have a similar table to yours except with more headers but it gives me an error on Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Hours"). "Unable to get pivot fields property"

Comment: I've added a picture at the most top. Its quite small but you can double click it. Those are my headers

Comment: @cresjoy I have again edited my answer to cater for filtering on a single person. My initial response was to only address your error problem. I was not convinced with the program approach but wanted to make it workable only. However I have demonstrated an approach as how this problem can be addressed. Further if there are problems with your data source is then make a simple pivot table recording macro while creating pivot table and it will lead you to the cause of the problem.

Comment: I get an error on "ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table1", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet6!R3C1", _
        TableName:="PivotTable7", DefaultVersion:=6"

Comment: Invalid Procedure and argument

Comment: The file I am reading from is May20. Do i change Sheet6 to may20?\

Comment: @cresjoy I have Excel 2016. Perhaps your Excel Version is different. As such I suggest you to record macro of your manual pivot creation so that you can examine its code to check for differences in syntax.. May20 is your datasource sheet and sheet6 is the new sheet where pivot table was created. If you again and again create pivot table sheet6 will be sheet7 or sheet8 etc.

Comment: I can also edit my answer to show you what I am looking for. I have edited my answer above. Please take a look

Comment: @cresjoy My first answer was in line with your current edit ie showing hours of all unique employees ID. The program code works on my computer without any problem. I have reworked on your edited data and it is working flawless. I have uploaded the file to dropbox. [Pivot table creation through wizard](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jul_2016/Pivot%20table%20creation%20through%20wizard.xlsm) for your tweaking. I may not be able to test any thing version specific to Excel 2007 since I don't have this on my PC. pl delete pivot table sheet before running program Macro.